# Retrieve Full Checkout Info using TFS API

Tags: c#, wpf, api, tfs

I am trying to get the list of checked out items from TFS using the following code:

I get the list of items as `ExtendedItem[] (var v)` but it doesn't have the checkout info (**LockOwner**, **LockOwnerDisplayName** and **LockStatus**) of an item it is not exclusively checked out.

Am I doing anything wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
VersionControlServer vcs = _tfsColl.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var v = vcs.GetExtendedItems(new ItemSpec[] { new ItemSpec(p.ServerItem, RecursionType.OneLevel)}, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.Any);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, to get the Check-out information of a file you need to find out the workspaces and then find what are all pending changes on those work spaces.

I found a useful post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41007e2d-3ea8-4641-a417-82a4bf8dcdd5/programmatically-check-if-file-is-checked-out-and-check-in-tfs-using-c?forum=tfsbuild) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.querypendingsets(v=vs.120).aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code to retrieve lock information:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("[collection URL]"));

            collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
            VersionControlServer vcs = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>(); 
            var pendingSets = vcs.QueryPendingSets(new string[] { "[server path]" }, RecursionType.OneLevel, null, null);
            foreach (PendingSet changeset in pendingSets)
            {
                foreach (PendingChange change in changeset.PendingChanges)
                {
                    if(change.IsLock)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Lock level:" + change.LockLevel);
                        Console.WriteLine("Locked By:" + changeset.OwnerName);
                        Console.WriteLine("Time:" + change.CreationDate);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @starain-mart, does that not need to be executed within the context of a Workspace?

Comment: How can you query PendingSets without a workspace? I guess I though that was a workspace feature....

Comment: The pending change actually has the workspace (local or remote) and there is queryWorkspace parameter, but we can specify null.

Comment: So if there is a pending change in many workspaces it will give me them all? Across all machines?

Comment: @MrHinsh The test result is that the pengding changes in server workspaces are included in the result. The locked pending change is included in the result. You need to specify workspace name and owner if you want to obtain local workspace pending changes.